# webpages vs aspnet tables, what is the difference?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm developing a website in asp.net 4.5 with mvc 5 and EntityFramework in Visual studio 2013 for web. 
In database the tables are named in this way:
webpages_Roles
webpages_Membership
....

But when i'm googling for help sometimes tables are named like:
AspNetRoles
AspNetUsers
... 
What is the difference between that?
When i'm googling for something (e.g authenthication), what should i ask for? is it ok to google "asp.net mvc authentication"?
Where can i find a detailed overview of Asp.net structure that exaplains things like that?

Answer (score 0):

That's 2 different technologies. But all about authentication and authorization.

`MembershipProvider` is older than `Identity` (that's what you can google)

Here you can read about [migration](https://www.asp.net/identity/overview/migrations/migrating-an-existing-website-from-sql-membership-to-aspnet-identity) from older to newer.

Comment: So i'm actually using MembershipProvider while i should use Identity?

Comment: It's better to use only new one if you have that option

Comment: Sorry, maybe i wasn't clear, what i'm using right now? MembershipProvider or Identity?

Comment: Identity, my friend, identity

Comment: You are sayin that i'm using identity but Win is saying that i'm using Membership Provider. Who should i trust?

Comment: Win say the same thing as I. You should use identity if you can. Now you use membership

Comment: Can you Tell me what type of references is used by Membership and what are for Identity?

Comment: Ok, now i understand.. Thanks!

Comment: The only things that is not Clear to me is that: How is it possible that Visual studio 2013 project template is using the old Membership as default?

Answer (score 0):

> Where can i find a detailed overview of Asp.net structure that
>   exaplains things like that?

Here is a little of history ***Membership*** -

- Membership Provider *(came with WebForm and WebPages)*
- Universal Providers
- Simple Membership *(replaced by ASP.NET Identity)*
- [ASP.NET Identity](https://www.asp.net/identity)

What you have is ***Membership Provider***. If you are developing a new web application, you want to use ***ASP.NET Identity***.

Comment: Are you sure i'm using Membership? Teo van kot is saying that i'm using Identity.

Comment: Can you Tell me what type of references is used by Membership and what are for Identity?

Comment: Ok, solved, now the only things that is not clear to me is that: How is it possible that Visual studio 2013 project template is using the old Membership as default?